# Extension of Solutions to Binary Equations

Tags: linear-programming

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874522/solutions-to-binary-equations) post, I asked a question regarding solutions to system of binary equations. The answer that was accepted provided a complete structural solution to the question. I have been working on a derivative of this problem that follows.

Given a matrix $A$ as defined in the initial problem. Is there an algebraic description of all $z$ values for which the algorithm described in the accepted answer yields a non empty solution space?

Comment: Calculation is done in $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: No, ${0,1}\in\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. Although it seems there's often a clean relation between the two.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer If you have any insight on these please let me know. I will likely award the bounty as there has not been much interest.

Comment: @Joseph Zambrano : if $x \cdot y \ne 0$ then $(x-y)\cdot \mathrm{row}_i(A) \ne \sum_{j=1}^n x_j$ , since at least one of the $x_j = 1$ will be canceled on the LHS.
i.e. If $z_i = 1$ then $x$ and $y$ must be normal.

Comment: Yes I agree.  In thing I can add is that the set of all possible $z$ values is parameterized by $s\in\{-1,0,1\}^n$ in the following way: $z_i(s)=\prod_k (1-1/2(s_k^2+s_k)+s_ka_{i,k})$ for each $i\in [m]$. However, it is often the case that $z_i(s)=z_i(s')$ for two distinct $s$ and $s'$.